# Aggregation change value of a boolean to string

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

Have a collection with records ,  Need to convert boolean values of a column to string :

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    passed_phd: true,
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    passed_phd: true,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    passed_phd: false,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    passed_phd: false,
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

how to change boolean value of the records to string.

value that has true(boolean) in passed_phd should be converted  to "yes"(string)

value that has  false(boolean) in passed_phd should be converted  to "no"(string)

```
[
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcw",
    name: "lucas",
    occupation: "scientist",
    passed_phd: "yes",
    age: 55,
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcx",
    name: "mark",
    occupation: "scientist",
    age: 45,
    passed_phd: "yes",
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbca",
    name: "stuart",
    occupation: "lab assistant",
    age: 25,
    passed_phd: "no",
    location: "texas",

  },
  {
    _id: "bmasndvhjbcq",
    name: "cooper",
    occupation: "physicist",
    age: 69,
    passed_phd: "no",
    location: "texas"
  }
]
```

mongodb version 4.0
.

Answer (score 0):

The [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html#cond-aggregation) aggregation pipeline operator can do this.

Beginning with MongoDB 4.2, these can be used in an update or in an aggregation pipeline, like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$set:{
            passed_phd:{
                        $cond:{
                               if:"$passed_phd",
                               then:"yes",
                               else:"no"
                              }
                        }
   }}
])
```

Comment: no, aggregation doesn't update the original documents.  If you want the output modified without changing the original, you can use the `$set` stage in an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: i just need the output modified and no need of updating the document.

Comment: the `$set` object is an aggregation stage, you can put that in your existing pipeline.

Comment: tried this `{'$passed_phd':true},{$set:{'$passed_phd':"yes"}` getting this error, passed_phd must not start with ' or $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210156/discussion-between-vebey74412-and-joe).

Comment: check this `  [{'passed_phd':true},{$set:{'passed_phd':"yes"}] getting Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.

Comment: I totally fell asleep (it was 5am here).  I rewrite the answer to use aggregation.